# How to use Spotfire Dense Rank function in R and How to Implement it R?

Tags: r, spotfire, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

> I need to calculate `Dense Rank` in R, like we use in **Spotfire**.  I
> tried `rank()` function in **R** But thats not worked. For This you
> can consider below Data Frame which have 5 columns such as `City, Region, Market, Year, Number_measure`
>
> You can consider below table for calculation
>
> ```
> city <- c("Nagpur", "Mumbai", "Pune", "Aurangabad", 
> "Auric City", "Solapur", "Nashik", "Aurangabad", "Auric City", "Latur", 
> "Mumbai", "Pune", "Aurangabad", "Auric City", "Auric City", 
> "Auric City", "Mumbai", "Pune", "Nagpur", "Mumbai", "Pune", 
> "Nagpur", "Mumbai", "Pune", "Aurangabad", "Auric City", 
> "Aurangabad", "Auric City","Solapur", "Nashik")
>
> Region <- c("Vidharbh", "Mumbai Region", "West Maharashtra", 
>              "Marathwada", "Marathwada", "West Maharashtra", 
>              "North Maharashtra", "Marathwada", "Marathwada", 
>              "Marathwada", "Mumbai Region", "West Maharashtra",
>              "Marathwada", "Marathwada", "Marathwada", "Marathwada", 
>              "Mumbai Region", "West Maharashtra", "Vidharbh", 
>              "Mumbai Region", "West Maharashtra", "Vidharbh", 
>              "Mumbai Region", "West Maharashtra", "Marathwada",
>              "Marathwada", "Marathwada", "Marathwada", 
>              "West Maharashtra", "North Maharashtra")
>
> Market <- c("Public", "Non Public", "Public", "Non Public", 
> "Public",  "Non Public", "Public", "Non Public", "Public", 
> "Non Public", "Public",  "Non Public", "Public", "Non Public", 
> "Public", "Non Public", "Public",  "Non Public","Public", 
> "Non Public", "Public", "Non Public", "Public",  
> "Non Public", "Public", "Non Public", "Public", "Non Public", 
> "Public",  "Non Public")
>
> Year <- c(2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2020, 2021, 2021, 
> 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2024, 2023, 2025, 2026, 2021, 
> 2022, 2022, 2023, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
> 2022, 2024, 2023, 2025, 2026)
>
> Number_Measure <- c(48877434, 48028137,  3912303, 13654456, 
> 30299576, 49090894, 53157520, 49631953, 43065620, 39234446, 
> 38298719,  4143774, 14631379, 31659688, 50734152, 55101038, 
> 51630622, 45200506, 41854513, 41215679,  4566837, 14384281, 
> 27952862, 44175298, 50610826, 50342076, 46282737, 44193037, 
> 44064169,  7849937)
>
> MainData <- data.frame(city, Region, Market, Year, Number_Measure)
>
> city            Region            Market       Year    Number_Measure
> Nagpur            Vidharbh          Public    2021       48877434
> Mumbai         Mumbai Region    Non Public    2022       48028137
> Pune  West        Maharashtra       Public    2022        3912303
> Aurangabad        Marathwada    Non Public    2023       13654456
> Auric City        Marathwada        Public    2020       30299576
> Solapur      West Maharashtra   Non Public    2021       49090894
> Nashik       North Maharashtra      Public    2021       53157520
> Aurangabad        Marathwada    Non Public    2022       49631953
> Auric City        Marathwada        Public    2022       43065620
> Latur             Marathwada    Non Public    2022       39234446
> Mumbai         Mumbai Region        Public    2022       38298719
> Pune  West        Maharashtra   Non Public    2024        4143774
> Aurangabad        Marathwada        Public    2023       14631379
> Auric City        Marathwada    Non Public    2025       31659688
> Auric City        Marathwada        Public    2026       50734152
> Auric City        Marathwada    Non Public    2021       55101038
> Mumbai         Mumbai Region        Public    2022       51630622
> Pune         West Maharashtra   Non Public    2022       45200506
> Nagpur            Vidharbh          Public    2023       41854513
> Mumbai         Mumbai Region    Non Public    2020       41215679
> Pune         West Maharashtra       Public    2021        4566837
> Nagpur            Vidharbh      Non Public    2021       14384281
> Mumbai         Mumbai Region        Public    2022       27952862
> Pune  West        Maharashtra   Non Public    2022       44175298
> Aurangabad        Marathwada        Public    2022       50610826
> Auric City        Marathwada    Non Public    2022       50342076
> Aurangabad        Marathwada        Public    2024       46282737
> Auric City        Marathwada    Non Public    2023       44193037
> Solapur      West Maharashtra       Public    2025       44064169
> Nashik       North Maharashtra  Non Public    2026       7849937
> ```

Now I Need to Find `Rank` on basis of `Number_Measure` and `Key` should be `City, Regions, Market, Year`

In **Spotfire** for this `Dense Rank` Function was used
For Reference- https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_ranking_functions.htm

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking, or what you're trying to do, or what you tried that didn't work, or where you need help

Comment: Hi Camille please check updated Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please Try `dense_rank` function from `dplyr` package
>
> `MainData$MeasureRank <- dense_rank(MainData$Number_Measure)`

Comment: Are you sure `dense_rank` is base? I'm only seeing it in dplyr. There's a base `rank` function

Comment: yes it's from dplyr not from base